# Mocking SessionContex using mockito causes a ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am starting with unit tests. I've made a change to a class in which I not inject the SessionContext so I can make a lookup when needed.

```
@Resource
private SessionContext ctx;
```

Now, in my test, I would like to inject it so I can mock the lookup method:

```
@Mock
private SessionContext ctx;
```

But when I run the test, I get:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/rpc/handler/MessageContext
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)    at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1860)   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.addAllMethods(ReflectUtils.java:349)
>     at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.getMethods(Enhancer.java:427)   at
>   org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:457)     at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
>     at
>   org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:217)
>     at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:378)
>     at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:318)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:110)
>     at
>   org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:62)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.createMethodInvocationControl(MockCreator.java:111)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.MockCreator.mock(MockCreator.java:60)
>     at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock(PowerMockito.java:143)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.standardInject(AnnotationEnabler.java:84)
>     at
>   org.powermock.api.extension.listener.AnnotationEnabler.beforeTestMethod(AnnotationEnabler.java:51)
>     at
>   org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.notifyBeforeTestMethod(PowerMockTestNotifierImpl.java:90)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:292)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:86)
>     at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:33)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:45)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:104)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   javax.xml.rpc.handler.MessageContext  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)     ... 39 more

I find it strange, because I have all the dependencies required (this code works in the real application).

How do I mock and inject  the SessionContext using mockito? (I can't change the mocking framework).

Answer (score 0):

I went through this same problem and solved by adding a dependency only on test scope!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-ejb_2.1_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using below jboss ee 7 spec then you might face this problem. It was previously included in jboss ee 6 spec but some how removed from ee 7 (I am  yet to  find it out)

```
<groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-7.0</artifactId>
```

to resolve this issue add below dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jaxrpc-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```